# sqlite3 can't import .csv file

Tags: csv, sqlite

I'm very new to DQL and sqlite.
I've created a very basic database and am trying to import data from a .csv file.
I watched a tutorial and have entered the following code:

```
.import countries.csv countries
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error: cannot open "countries.csv"
```

I'm sure im over looking something easy here. countries.csv is a file I made in excel and saved as a .csv. In Text Editor it opens as a normal comma seperated values file

Comment: Close Excel before you import it. Excel locks files it has open exclusively, so while it has them open every other process will get "Access Denied" for them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have Excel closed but am still getting the same error

Comment: Well, that was the non-obvious thing. The obvious thing: Use an absolute path to the CSV.

Comment: Not sure exactly how to write the absolute path. Have tried

Comment: sorry, hadn't finished typing. Have tried .import C:/Users/me/Desktop/SQL Data/countries.csv countries but still got the same error

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv). Use quotes for paths that contain spaces.

Comment: Since the solution was so simple, I think it's in order if you just delete the question. That, or you write your own answer, that's all-right as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem - any path that contains spaces needs to use quotation marks

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash by using doubles. I've had success using two backslashes in the path when doing this on Windows.

Try this out:

```
sqlite> .import "C:\\working\\tmp\\data.txt" tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `~/` on mac, but needed to use path eg `/Users/me/`.

Comment: I've made the substitution, but it didn't help, even with a quoted file name.

Answer (score -1):

Oh! It took me few hours to solve the problem and it nearly drove me mad! I had saved the csv file in a folder while I didn't change the terminal into it. I used cs50ide and after I typed in 'cd folder/' and then tryed again, it worked. Hope this can help u.